# complex numbers and 2x2 matrices

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, group-theory, complex-numbers

Is it correct that set ${\mathbb C}$ is ***isomorphic*** to the set of following 2x2 matrices:
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a &-b\\
b &a 
\end{array}\right)
$$
$a \in {\mathbb R}$ and $b \in {\mathbb R} $?

In other words: are these two sets identical?

Comment: Yes, these are isomorphic fields, but no, that does not mean the two sets are equal.

Comment: Actually a meant that they are "identical" (with quotes). Sometimes when there is isomorphism between two sets it is said that they are alike.

Comment: the term is 'essentially the same'.

Comment: I was reluctant to vote to close-as-duplicate in this direction because the only answer on the previous Question is quite thin (both Q's are quite old), and indeed the framing of the issue of field isomorphism is there broken into separate problems about the additive and multiplicative groups.  It's not a bad idea to recognize the two Questions are essentially the same, but the representation of complex numbers in this fashion surely deserves a thorough explanation somewhere on Math.SE.

Comment: @hardmath I used the other question as the "original" because a third question was closed as a duplicate of the other question, and also because of the weird "identical sets" thing here...

Comment: Also, this question doesn't mention "group" or "ring" isomorphism, but the answer assume "group" (there was not group-theory tag at that point). So the other question is more general. (But possibly the other question+answer should just be improved?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Provided that $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$, that means the determinant is non-zero.

the map $\varphi: (\mathbb{C}-\{0\},.) \to (M, \times)$ given by $(a+bi) \mapsto \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a &-b\\
b &a 
\end{array}\right)$ is an isomorphism. You can check it easily ($M$ is the set of all such matrices and $\times$ is matrix multiplication)

Comment: What is the reason for $a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$? I think that zero matrix is absolutely equivalent to zero complex number, isn't it?

Comment: @mechanician: Well, if you look at complex numbers as a ring, then you don't need that, but if you look at complex numbers as a group under multiplication, you do need that condition to ensure the existence of inverses. I assumed you considered them isomorphic as 'groups'. In what category you're talking about these two being isomorphic?

Comment: Ok, I understand it.

Comment: Should we not have $a^2+b^2 \ge 0$, because the absolute value of a complex number cannot be smaller than zero?