# Is the following space connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, connectedness

Question is to see if $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}x&-y\\y&x\end{bmatrix}: x,y\in \mathbb{R}, x^2+y^2=1\right\}$

Just before this there was a question which asks if Gl$_2(\mathbb{R})$ is connected or not..

Then considering determinant map, I saw that image of determinant map on Gl$_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$ a disconnected subset.. So, Gl$_2(\mathbb{R})$ can not be connected..

In this case i see that image of determinant map is connected, just the singleton set $\{1\}$..

I can not conclude anything from this..

Help me to clear this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This set is $SO(2)$, it is connected, it is the image of $f:R\rightarrow GL_2(R)$ defined by

$f(t)= \pmatrix{cost & -sint\cr sint &cost}$,

Comment: The "continuous" image of.... +1

Comment: I was thinking continuous image arguments are mostly used to prove that something is not connected.. This is the first time i am seeing that continuous image is used to prove connectedness.. +1

Comment: @cello How are continuity arguments used to prove non-connectedness?

Comment: @cello Thank you. I doubt that. If the image is not connected and the function's continuous then all we can say is the image has to be some component of the codomain. For example, any continuous function $\;\Bbb R\to\Bbb Q\;$ has to be a constant one

Comment: @cello Thank you, and sorry for not being clear. I meant that $\;f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb Q\;$ continuous $\;\implies f\;$  is constant. It's easy to see and I mentioned that because it is the closest to what you said.

Comment: @cello I just wondered how continuity can be used, as you said,  to show non-connectedness, that's all. I just can't see it. Do you have a specific example? Besides this, who said that in my example $\;\{1\}\;$ is the image? In fact it can be any point in $\;\Bbb Q\;$....but ONLY one point.

Comment: @cello Oh, I see now. I misunderstood. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you @Joanpemo... I would like to delete all my comments as this is just a misunderstanding and i want to keep this plain...

Answer (score 0):

Because of [this MSE-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570709/complex-numbers-and-2x2-matrices) we know that the above set is given by the circle group
$$
\{ z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|=1\},
$$
also known as $SO_2(\mathbb{R})$, which is connected but not simply connected.

Comment: That was useful... Thanks..