# If $ac+bd=0$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$, then is it true that $a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers such that $ac+bd=0$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$. Is it true that $a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2=0$?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you think this might be true?

Comment: It is true but I would like to find an easy way of showing it.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for the trivial question. I am in fact trying to find a ``liner algebraic'' proof of this simple fact, not involving divisions. If you interpret $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ as two real vectors, is there a simpler way to achieve the solution?

Comment: "Simpler" way depends on your opinion. You can use some algebraic identity, or determinants of matrices, or orthogonal matrices, but this will not be easier. It just will look better in the end than doing a trivial computation. For other ideas, see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2608031/find-non-zero-real-numbers-a-b-c-d-such-that-a2c2-b2d2-and-abcd-0?noredirect=1)

Comment: The assumptions on the $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ you have, just say that the columns of $A$ must be orthogonal to each other. So compute $AA^T$ and $A^TA$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean here? $A^TA$ is a multiple of the identity, but why are you considering $AA^T$?

Comment: Did you compute both? On one product the diagonal elements are $a^2+b^2$ and $c^2+d^2$, so equal diagonal elements, and the other product has $a^2+c^2$ and $b^2+d^2$. They are then also equal. Note that this is what you want to prove.

Comment: draw some pictures. You have orthogonal vectors of the same length, in the plane.  Given one vector $(a,b)$  the other vector is $(c,d) = \pm (-b,a).$  Now we want to know how $a^2 + c^2$ compares with $b^2 + d^2$  Well, with $c = \pm b$  we see $a^2 + c^2 = a^2 + b^2$  Next, with $d = \pm a,$ we see $b^2 + d^2  = b^2 + a^2$

Answer (score 0):

We may assume that $b$ is nonzero, because otherwise $b=ac=0$, so $a=0$ or $c=0$, and we are done. So we can define $d:=-\frac{ac}{b}$. Then the second and third equation become the same equation, namely
$$
a^2b^2 - a^2c^2 + b^4 - b^2c^2=0.
$$
So we are done.